# How to use if_else with sql query in RODBC package R

Tags: r, if-statement, rodbc

I am using the RODBC package in R to run a SQL query. I'd like to add a simple condition to run this query. I am able to get results from the below query

```
library(RODBC)
database1 <- odbcConnect(dsn = "<database_name>")
sqlQuery(database1, "SELECT * FROM TABLE")
```

But when I add an ifelse() statement to it, then it doesn't work

```
ifelse(1<2, sqlQuery(database1, "SELECT * FROM TABLE"), "")
```

What really went wrong here?

Unfortunately, I cannot produce a reproducible example as the question needs a database connection.

Thanks!

Comment: `ifelse` is something very specific, and is not "just" another way of doing a regular `if () else` clause. You want just a normal `if () {} else {}` structure.

Comment: @joran thanks! That worked.